# Removing an element from a nested data structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am currently working the knockout.js framework. I find it easy and great to implement. I am working on a contacts form similar to their example shown at knockoutjs.com . The form is composed of several fields that can be dynamically added or deleted. This is where I am running into a wall: I am trying to disable  the `delete` button if there is less 2 contact fields left in the form. This is causing issues however and making the form not render properly and disabling the delete function. Here is the full code: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/2281/)

knockout.js

```
var ContactsModel = function(contacts) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function(contact) {
        return { firstName: contact.firstName, lastName: contact.lastName, phones: ko.observableArray(contact.phones) };
    }));

    self.addContact = function() {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            phones: ko.observableArray()
        });
    };

    self.removeContact = function(contact) {
        self.contacts.remove(contact);
    };

    self.addPhone = function(contact) {
        contact.phones.push({
            type: "",
            number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function(phone) {
        $.each(self.contacts(), function() { this.phones.remove(phone) })
    };

    self.save = function() {
        self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
    };

    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
};

ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
```

HTML

```
 <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeContact, enable: contacts().length < 2'>Delete</a></div>
```

Comment: You really ought to show the relevant HTML and code in this post.  Questions that have no significant meaning without an external reference are not permitted here on StackOverflow for a variety of reasons, but the main one is that they easily become invalid questions (of no future use) when the external reference is changed or removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your binding is wrong, should be `enable: $root.contacts().length > 2`,

Second, `enable` binding does NOT work on `anchor` tag, it only works on input, select, and textarea.

Please consider hide it or add condition in your `removeContact` implementation.

http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/2284/

```
<div data-bind="if: $root.contacts().length > 2">
  <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeContact'>Delete</a>
</div>
```

Comment: another thought is your `removePhone`, it's better to give contact object a constructor, and move `removePhone` implementation to the contact object itself, so you don't have to do the crazy loop on contacts for simply deleting one phone number.

Comment: It makes sense now. My binding was incorrect. Great! You are right. I will change `removePhone` to the contact object.

Answer (score 0):

The JSFiddle was not working well for me, but, if I understand correctly, the delete link is not being disabled properly.

I noticed in your HTML, you had this:

```
<a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeContact, enable: contacts().length > 0'>Delete</a>
```

This will still allow the link to be enabled if you have 1 or more items. If you want it to disable when you have 1 or fewer, you'll need it to be this:

```
<a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeContact, enable: contacts().length > 1'>Delete</a>
```

Let me know if this did not answer your question.